# Starting at particular line, print surrounding lines that match pattern

Tags: awk, grep, diff

If I get back a `diff` that shows, for example:

```
7c7
< backup=false
---
> backup=true
```

How would I then be able to print the surrounding lines that match the pattern "where the quoted Tags string starts and ends"? For example, with the text below, if line 7 changed, I'd like to get the content contained within that line + the lines containing the quoted string which spans over an unknown number of lines:

Example text (original):

```
Name    Monitoring  Tags
i-RBwPyvq8wPbUhn495 enabled "some:tags:with:colons=some:value:with:colons-and-dashes/and/slashes/yay606-values-001
some:other:tag:with-colons-and-hyphens=MACHINE NAME 
Name=NAMETAG    
backup=true"
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01  
backup=false    
Name=SOMENAME"
```

Example text (change):

```
Name    Monitoring  Tags
i-RBwPyvq8wPbUhn495 enabled "some:tags:with:colons=some:value:with:colons-and-dashes/and/slashes/yay606-values-001
some:other:tag:with-colons-and-hyphens=MACHINE NAME 
Name=NAMETAG    
backup=true"
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01  
backup=true 
Name=SOMENAME"
```

...I'd like to somehow then return:

```
i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP   enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01  
backup=true   
Name=SOMENAME"
```

Comment: are those prefix numbers actually appear within your files?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest they do not appear, I was just trying to represent it in the example. I'll remove them, actually, as it's a small enough example I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and BEGINFILE, this will simply treat each multi-line record as a record instead of its component lines individually:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGINFILE {
    # make sure RS is the default so we can read/skip each header line
    RS="\n"
}

FNR==1 {
    # skip the header line and set RS to capture multi-line records
    RS="[^\"]+\"[^\"]+\"\n"
    next
}

# at this point each record is stored in RT instead of $0

NR==FNR {
    a[FNR] = RT
    next
}

RT != a[FNR] {
    printf "Record #%d:\n", FNR-1
    printf "< %s", a[FNR]
    printf "> %s", RT
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk orig change
Record #2:
< i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01
backup=false
Name=SOMENAME"
> i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01
backup=true
Name=SOMENAME"
```

Updated to use the "Name" column as a unique identifier, see the comments below:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGINFILE {
    # make sure RS is the default so we can read/skip each header line
    RS="\n"
}

FNR==1 {
    # skip the header line and set RS to capture multi-line records
    RS="[^\"]+\"[^\"]+\"\n"
    next
}

# at this point each record is stored in RT instead of $0
{ $0=RT }

NR==FNR {
    a[$1] = $0
    next
}

{
    if ( $1 in a ) {
        if ( $0 != a[$1] ) {
            printf "Record %s changed:\n", $1
            printf "< %s", a[$1]
            printf "> %s", $0
        }
        delete a[$1]
    }
    else {
        printf "Record %s added:\n", $1
        printf "> %s", $0
    }
}
END {
    for ( i in a ) {
        printf "Record %s deleted:\n", i
        printf "< %s", a[i]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk orig change
Record i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP changed:
< i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01
backup=false
Name=SOMENAME"
> i-sMEwh2MXj3q47yWWP enabled "description=RANDOM BUSINESS INT01
backup=true
Name=SOMENAME"
```

Comment: That most certainly did it. Thank you, awk wizard Ed Morton! Thank you for the comments as well, great learning experience.

Comment: One thing I did realize is this kind of blows up if the record is new/didn't exist at all in the orig file, the diff isn't then accurate because it will pull incorrect data. Hmmm. Looking into ways around this.

Comment: It's doing a record-order by record-order comparison so if a record is added or removed from the "changes" file then it'll be printed as the first difference. If those "Name" column values are unique identifiers for each record then we could populate and compare values in `a[]` using those as the index rather than the line number. Otherwise, there's nothing you can robustly do to separate additions/deletions from changes.

Comment: The name column is unique. I've just been struggling with sorting them because of the multiple lines each record contains.

Comment: You don't need to sort them. Give me a min and I'll post an alternative.

Comment: Done, take a look now. If you're going to do anything else with them then I recommend writing a script to replace the newlines from inside the quotes and then you can just run the standard UNIX tools on the result.

Comment: Very much appreciated for the additional support. Double accepted ;) That works beautifully.